# Deep reinforcement learning for similar observations but need totally different actions, how to solve it?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

For DRL using neural networks, like DQN, if there is a task that needs total different actions at similar observations, is NN going to show its weakness at this moment? Will two near input to the NN generate similar output? If so, it cannot get the different the task need?

**For instance:**
the agent can choose discrete action from [A,B,C,D,E], here is the observation by a set of plugs in a binary list [0,0,0,0,0,0,0].

For observation [1,1,1,1,1,1,1] and [1,1,1,1,1,1,0] they are quite similar but if the agent should conduct action A at [1,1,1,1,1,1,1] but action D at [1,1,1,1,1,1,0]. Those two observation are too closed on the distance so the DQN may not easily get the proper action? How to solve?

**One more thing:**
One hot encoding is a way to improve the distance between observations. It is also a common and useful way for many supervised learning tasks. But one hot will also increase the dimension heavily.

Comment: [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to ask theoretical questions related to reinforcement learning, so I suggest that you ask your question there. If you ask it there, please, delete it from here (to avoid cross-posting, which is generally discouraged).

Answer (score 0):

> Will two near input to the NN generate similar output ?

Artificial neural networks, by nature, are non-linear function approximators. Meaning that for two given similar inputs, the output can be very different.

You might get an intuition on it considering this example, two very similar pictures (the one on the right just has some light noise added to it) give very different results for the model.

[image]

> For observation [1,1,1,1,1,1,1] and [1,1,1,1,1,1,0] they are quite similar but if the agent should conduct action A at [1,1,1,1,1,1,1] but action D at [1,1,1,1,1,1,0]. Those two observation are too closed on the distance so the DQN may not easily get the proper action ?

I see no problem with this example, a properly trained NN should be able to map the desired action for both inputs. Furthermore, in your example the input vectors contain binary values, a single difference in these vectors (meaning that they have a Hamming distance of 1) is big enough for the neural net to classify them properly.

Also, the non-linearity in neural networks comes from the activation functions, hope this helps !